# Null Pointer Exception in executeObjectLevelReadQuery of EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, oracle11g, eclipselink

I'm using eclipseLink 2.5.2 in my project and sometimes I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1168)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3214)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.executeBatchQuery(CollectionMapping.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.extractResultFromBatchQuery(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.extractResultFromBatchQuery(CollectionMapping.java:955)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.BatchValueHolder.instantiate(BatchValueHolder.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder.instantiate(QueryBasedValueHolder.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiateImpl(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiate(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectSet.buildDelegate(IndirectSet.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectSet.getDelegate(IndirectSet.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectSet.contains(IndirectSet.java:349)
    at com.services.CategoryServiceImpl.categoryContainsCareType(CategoryServiceImpl.java:305)
    at
```

This is the section that the relationship between careType and category is defined and the exception happens where the `category.getCareTypes()` is invoked:

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity=CareTypeJPAImpl.class) @JoinTable(
        name="J_CARE_TYPE_CATEGORY",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="CATEGORY_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="CARE_TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
@org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.BatchFetch(value=org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.BatchFetchType.JOIN,size=990)
private Set<CareType> careTypes = new HashSet<CareType>();
```

I looked at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.core/2.5.2/org/eclipse/persistence/queries/ReadAllQuery.java#ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery%28%29) but don't understand much